# How to build a SQLCipher driver for PyQt5

Tags: python, sqlite, qt, pyqt5, sqlcipher

I am having some troubles in order to build a SQLCipher driver for PyQt5. I checked some ways of building a Qt SQLCipher driver plugin, but I am fairly new to this world and I only know Python, so I don't understand it nor understand how to make it work for PyQt5 without using plugins. I also saw that I building a driver as a class is possible, but I don't have any idea of how to build this driver. I have some disconnected information about drivers, Qt and PyQt5, but I just can't figure out how to put it all together. I also tried to investigate how the other SQL drivers are built in PyQt5, but I only found some wraps around C++ that I don't understand.

Anybody can help me to build a SQLCipher that I can use in PyQt5, as a Python class or any other different ways?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I forgot to add that my OS is Windows 10 64 bit.

Comment: what is your OS?

Comment: I forgot to say it sorry. It's windows 10 64 bits

Comment: You have to compile the plugin with Qt (the same version of PyQt5) with C++ and Visual Studio and then it is copied in the path of the plugins

Comment: With the path of plugins do you mean in the PyQt5 library?

Comment: Yes, but that is the simplest task. Try to compile that plugin

Comment: Ok, I will try it right now and tell you if it works. Thank you very much!

Comment: I have limitations at the time of downloading .exe and installing new programs, because I am working in a company network that has some restrictions. Do you know if I can build the driver myself as a Python class as they do here https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/overviews/sql-driver.html#sql-database-drivers ? If yes, how?

Comment: mmm Realize that the procedure indicated in that link does what it indicates.

Comment: I'm having a lot of problems for building the driver, because following some tutorial I find the things I am doing different to those mentioned (including pahts, available versions and so on). I also have troubles downloading some things due to network restrictions. What do you mean by your answer? What does it indicates? Isn't it possible in PyQt5 to build a SQLCipher driver creating a python class? If possible, how? Thanks a lot for your time and sorry for reopening a new question.

Comment: 1) I do not have MacOS, in Linux it is relatively simple but you must have experience in compiling projects in C++ so without quality information on your part it is difficult to help, if you have a network that complicates too much so that you will have to solve your. 2) The plugins in Qt for any derivative are in principle implemented in C++, and not in python since the basic driver is written in a language like C or C++.